# Windows application for tracking web pages?

Tags: windows, monitoring, webpage

Can you recommend a ***stand-alone*** Windows application (that excludes Firefox plug-ins) for alerting when web pages change their content or length?

Preferably it should be possible to specify some threshold for the minimum amount of difference in content similarity or content length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Update Patrol](http://www.updatepatrol.com/features.html) in the past and it's pretty good.  It costs money although there is a free trial.

It is possible to specify thresholds to some extent:

> Ignore dynamic data in page
>   comparisons, e.g. number of visitors,
>   dates, timestamps etc. This is
>   configurable using regular expressions
>   (a pattern matching syntax) for
>   maximum flexibility.